# RewriteBase on a webserver with no-aliases

Tags: mod-rewrite, centos

I'm working on a website which is runs on a dedicated server. The setup is a CentOS machine and Apache but without any aliases (it's the only website runs on the server). The website files are located at `/var/www/html/` and mod_rewrite logs are not enabled.

I have tried both `RewriteBase /var/www/html/` and `RewriteBase /`, but without any success. I'm sure that my rewrite rules are correct as they're working on my local machine.

Does anyone know what should be the `RewriteBase` value?

P.S. `.htaccess` is located at website root at `/var/www/html/`

**Update**

The problem wasn't `RewriteBase`, but the `AllowOverride` was set to `None` for security reason.

Comment: ¿Where is the htaccess file?

Comment: @faa website root `/var/www/html/`

Comment: If in root, the `RewriteBase` should be `/`. ¿What's the problem and why do you think changing `RewriteBase` will solve it?

Comment: @faa well I'm not totally sure about what is the problem, RewriteBase is whatever I can imagine of. That's the only difference between my machine and server setup: Aliases. By the way, I'm receiving 404 error, while trying to reach a search-engine-friendly url like example.com/about/.

Comment: If there is an alias, the base must be set accordingly. Check this [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for RewriteBase. There is an example similar to your case that might help.

Comment: @faa I checked the `httpd.conf` right now, they `AllowOverride` has set to `None` for the security reason, I'll ask to change that, that should works then ...

Comment: @faa it's working now, by the way, thanks for your effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the answer from above, because it is in the comments and I had the same issue. This answer is for people who may have the same problem in the future.

In the configuration file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
AllowOverride None
```

needs to be changed to

`AllowOverride All` in the `<Directory "/var/www/html">` section

This will allow you to use a `.htaccess` file in the web root of your site.

After that run the command `service httpd restart` to restart the Apache service